# Using for loop to loop through object and throws error after reaching it's data's length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json object which I am using a for loop to loop through and when the loop reaches the data's length, I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RoomName' of undefined

It looks like it wants to keep on looping and not finding anything.

Why is it doing that? shouldn't it have broke out of the for loop once it reached the data's length of 4?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        var data2 = [
            { "RoomID": 1, "RoomName": "Room 1", "Areas": [{ "id": 1, "AreaName": "Area 1" }, { "id": 10, "AreaName": "Area 10" }] },
            { "RoomID": 2, "RoomName": "Room 2", "Areas": [{ "id": 2, "AreaName": "Area 2" }, { "id": 20, "AreaName": "Area 20" }] },
            { "RoomID": 3, "RoomName": "Room 3", "Areas": [{ "id": 3, "AreaName": "Area 3" }, { "id": 30, "AreaName": "Area 30" }, { "id": 35, "AreaName": "Area 35" }] },
            { "RoomID": 4, "RoomName": "Room 4", "Areas": [{ "id": 4, "AreaName": "Area 4" }, { "id": 40, "AreaName": "Area 40" }] }
        ];
        
        
        // Data2
        console.log("data2's length is: " + data2.length);
        
        for (i = 0; i <= data2.length; i++) {
        
            console.log(data2[i].RoomName);

            if (data2[i].Areas.length > 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < data2[i].Areas.length; j++) {
                
                    console.log(" - " + data2[i].Areas[j].AreaName);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the "=" in this line

```
for (i = 0; i <= data2.length; i++) {
```

If you change it to

```
for (i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
```

it should be fine.

This occurs because the array is zero indexed and so the length of the array is 1 more than the index of the iteration.

Comment: Yep that did the trick, i'll accept as answer when i am allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You have the for loop as following:

```
for (i = 0; i <= data2.length; i++)
```

But the last index of the array is `data2.length - 1`. And thats why your last element is `undefined`. Change the above line to the following code

```
for (i = 0; i < data2.length; i++)
```

Here is the working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        var data2 = [
            { "RoomID": 1, "RoomName": "Room 1", "Areas": [{ "id": 1, "AreaName": "Area 1" }, { "id": 10, "AreaName": "Area 10" }] },
            { "RoomID": 2, "RoomName": "Room 2", "Areas": [{ "id": 2, "AreaName": "Area 2" }, { "id": 20, "AreaName": "Area 20" }] },
            { "RoomID": 3, "RoomName": "Room 3", "Areas": [{ "id": 3, "AreaName": "Area 3" }, { "id": 30, "AreaName": "Area 30" }, { "id": 35, "AreaName": "Area 35" }] },
            { "RoomID": 4, "RoomName": "Room 4", "Areas": [{ "id": 4, "AreaName": "Area 4" }, { "id": 40, "AreaName": "Area 40" }] }
        ];
        
        
        // Data2
        console.log("data2's length is: " + data2.length);
        
        for (i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        
            console.log(data2[i].RoomName);

            if (data2[i].Areas.length > 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < data2[i].Areas.length; j++) {
                
                    console.log(" - " + data2[i].Areas[j].AreaName);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<=` data2.length in your first for loop.

#### Reason why this fails...

```
console.log(data2.length) //expected '4'
```

your array's actual length is '3' since arrays start at 0. but `.length` returns its length starting with 1 instead.

So if `i===4` it is **equal** to `data2.length` but the highest point in `data2` would be `3`

```
console.log(typeof data2[3]) expected: 'object'
console.log(typeof data2[4]) expected: 'undefined'
```